# Large Titles weird behavior in Split View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller

My app is really simple, what you can see in the GIF below is a transition between the master and detail view of a UISplitViewController. The two views have `prefersLargeTitles = true`. The master,named "Chapitres", is a UITableViewController and the detail, named "Théorie", a standard UIViewController with a UITableView inside (there is the same problem even if the two are UITableViewController).
As you can see the title has a weird behavior, when the detail view appears, the title is small but the content has a top margin as if the title was big. Then, when a scroll is perform, the title instantly gets bigger.

[image]

The setup in storyboard is like in the screenshot below with a ShowDetail relationship between the "Chapitre" View and the "Théorie" View.

[image]

Does anyone knows what I'm doing wrong ?
Thank you !

Comment: That doesn’t look like a correctly constructed spilt view controller. I suggest you start over with the Split View app template and don’t mess with the structure this time. Note for example that Apples Mail app doesn’t display this issue.

Comment: Also there is a touchy interplay between large titles and many other properties. You are not giving any info about your settings  and when / how you set them, so it is hard to help. But at the least, make sure that AlwaysBounceVertical is turned on for all your table views and that they underlap the navigation bar.